# Как вычислить высоту пирамиды (треугольника) из окружностей?

Tags: геометрия

Задача из реальной жизни. Погрузка труб. Трубы грузятся в первый слой - 3 трубы. Второй слой - 2 трубы. Третий слой - одна труба. Получается такой треугольник, где труба каждого следующего слоя лежит между двумя нижними трубами.

Вопрос: как рассчитать высоту от верхней точки верхней трубы до пола?

Нужно понять сколько слоёв труб мы сможем уложить на складе таким образом?

Comment: а не выгоднее класть трубы крест на крест? предположив, что высота склада может достигать n - высоты, получается мы высоту делим на диаметр трубы - получаем примерное кол-во труб между полом и потолком. Таким образом пустоты на складе буду увеличиваться с каждым слоем новых труб. И это я не беру в расчет, длину трубы, ширину и длину склада.

Comment: Нет не выгоднее именно из за пустот.

Answer (score 5):

Ну к программированию и к вычислительной геометрии это не имеет отношения, просто школьная геометрия

```
h =  2*R*(Sqrt(3)+1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

KC - высота равностороннего треугольника `4*R*Sqrt(3)/2`

Для данного примера `2*2*(1.732+1)=10.92`

---

Задача складирования:

`N` слоев труб при плотнейшей укладке дают высоту

```
 H = 2*R + (N-1)*R*Sqrt(3)
```

Отсюда количество слоев для высоты H

```
 H/R = 2 + (N-1)*Sqrt(3) 
 (N-1)*Sqrt(3) =  H/R - 2
 N = 1 + (H/R - 2)/Sqrt(3)
 или в диаметрах
 N = 1 + 2*(H/D - 1)/Sqrt(3) ~= 1 + 1.1547*(H/D - 1) = 1.1547*H/D -  0.1547
```

От этого взять целую часть. Для вашего примера 15 слоев

Comment: [Опередили меня](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWLJq.jpg) буквально на чуть чуть :)

Comment: @tym32167 Тоже, наверное, пояснение дольше рисовали, чем считали ;)

Comment: Ага, там и считать нечего особо, школьная программа :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Но мы ищем высоту от пола до верхней точки последней трубы (верхнего ряда). А вы считаете просто высоту внутреннего треугольника.

Comment: @Максим Нет, я посчитал то, что нужно, добавив два радиуса. Формула вверху.

Comment: Я понял большое спасибо. Sqrt (3) - это квадратный корень из 3? И 3 - это количество слоёв труб? Помогите пожалуйста еще чутка. Максимальная высота для погрузки на склад 12.4м. Диаметр труб 0.91м. Сколько слоёв можно погрузить и какая будет их высота? Простите, я простой зав склада, не так умён, как вы.

Comment: `Sqrt (3) - это кубический корень из 3?` да, примерное значение 1.732.  3 здесь не имеет отношения к количестве слоев, оно получается из теоремы Пифагора. Про слои допишу

Comment: Я разобрался. Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Максим ОК, не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer